# Change Document Root for Laravel Instance

Tags: laravel, apache, dns, centos, cpanel

- I have a dedicated server running CentOS.
- I have installed
  WHM/Cpanel. On my server, I have a domain (example.com) and a user
  (example).

The website domain example.com points to /home/example/public_html/. However, my project is Laravel, so the index point is in /public. I need to change the document root from 
`/home/example/public_html/` to `/home/example/public_html/public`

I ran the following commands:

```
nano /var/cpanel/userdata/example/example.com
nano /var/cpanel/userdata/example/example.com_SSL

rm -vf /var/cpanel/userdata/example/example.com.cache
rm -vf /var/cpanel/userdata/example/example.com_SSL.cache

/scripts/updateuserdatacache
/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf

service httpd restart
```

**The problem:**
When I run these commands, I see that nothing changed and I see DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION page of Laravel index.php (root not public).

When I run these commands for an empty project I see the results, and when I copy and paste the Laravel project I again see the permission denied page.

What is it?

Comment: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: @Thomas as I said I give Permission Denied page of Laravel framework. I don't have problems with Linux file permissions. Please, read the question again.